# Django,django-modeltranslation

Tags: django, django-modeltranslation

I'm new with modeltranslation and I have a problem. When I do the manage.py makemigrations myapp command after creating my model and registering the fields to translate in translation.py the modeltranslation app doesn't add the translated field to the model. The fields are in the table though.

modeltranslation: Registered 0 models for translation () [pid: 8333].

in my setting.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('hi', _('Hindi')),
    ('en', _('English')),

    ('ru', _('Russian')),
    ('ur', _('Urdu')),
    ('zh', _('Chinese')),
)



LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hi'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
from modeltranslation.translator import translator
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'hi'

MODELTRANSLATION_LANGUAGES = ('hi', 'en')

MODELTRANSLATION_FALLBACK_LANGUAGES = ('hi', 'en')

MODELTRANSLATION_PREPOPULATE_LANGUAGE = 'hi'


MODELTRANSLATION_TRANSLATION_FILES = (
    'i18ntest.translation',
)
```

in my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy
from django.conf import settings

    class MyThing(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(help_text=ugettext_lazy('This is the help text'),max_length = 150,null = True, blank = True)
        def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# Create your models here.


    class Profile(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 150,null = True, blank = True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

in my translations.py

```
from modeltranslation.translator import register,translator, TranslationOptions

from i18ntest.models import MyThing

@register(MyThing)

    class MyThingTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
        fields = ('name',

)

#translator.register(MyThing, MyThingTranslationOptions)
```

i'm using django-modeltranslation 0.12 with django 1.10

and server status is

```
(envi18n) vinod@vinod-H81M-S:~/vinod/i18n/i18n$ ./manage.py runserver
modeltranslation: Registered 0 models for translation () [pid: 9065].
modeltranslation: Registered 0 models for translation () [pid: 9068].
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 22, 2017 - 12:26:35
Django version 1.10, using settings 'i18n.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the translation file name. I must be `translation.py`, singular.